# Remove diacritics from a string

Tags: php, diacritics

Is it possible? This is my input string:

```
ľ š č ť ž ý á í é Č Á Ž Ý
```

This is the output I want:

```
l s c t z y a i e C A Z Y
```

Comment: This java related question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from

Comment: I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465990/how-to-handle-diacritics-accents-when-rewriting-pretty-urls/466117#466117 has a better solution than the accepted answer here.

Comment: basically: `$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $dirty);`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a function that Wordpress uses and works nice. Here's the working code with output.

```
<?php

function seems_utf8($str)
{
    $length = strlen($str);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
        elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
        elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
        else return false; # Does not match any model
        for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
            if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Converts all accent characters to ASCII characters.
 *
 * If there are no accent characters, then the string given is just returned.
 *
 * @param string $string Text that might have accent characters
 * @return string Filtered string with replaced "nice" characters.
 */
function remove_accents($string) {
    if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
        return $string;

    if (seems_utf8($string)) {
        $chars = array(
        // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
        chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(135) => 'C', chr(195).chr(136) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(137) => 'E', chr(195).chr(138) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(139) => 'E', chr(195).chr(140) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(141) => 'I', chr(195).chr(142) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(143) => 'I', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
        chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
        chr(195).chr(159) => 's', chr(195).chr(160) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(161) => 'a', chr(195).chr(162) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(163) => 'a', chr(195).chr(164) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(165) => 'a', chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
        chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(177) => 'n', chr(195).chr(178) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(179) => 'o', chr(195).chr(180) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(181) => 'o', chr(195).chr(182) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(185) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(186) => 'u', chr(195).chr(187) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(188) => 'u', chr(195).chr(189) => 'y',
        chr(195).chr(191) => 'y',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
        chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
        chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
        chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
        chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
        chr(197).chr(148) => 'R',chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(150) => 'R',chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(152) => 'R',chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(154) => 'S',chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(156) => 'S',chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(158) => 'S',chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
        chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
        chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's',
        // Euro Sign
        chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E',
        // GBP (Pound) Sign
        chr(194).chr(163) => '');

        $string = strtr($string, $chars);
    } else {
        // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8
        $chars['in'] = chr(128).chr(131).chr(138).chr(142).chr(154).chr(158)
            .chr(159).chr(162).chr(165).chr(181).chr(192).chr(193).chr(194)
            .chr(195).chr(196).chr(197).chr(199).chr(200).chr(201).chr(202)
            .chr(203).chr(204).chr(205).chr(206).chr(207).chr(209).chr(210)
            .chr(211).chr(212).chr(213).chr(214).chr(216).chr(217).chr(218)
            .chr(219).chr(220).chr(221).chr(224).chr(225).chr(226).chr(227)
            .chr(228).chr(229).chr(231).chr(232).chr(233).chr(234).chr(235)
            .chr(236).chr(237).chr(238).chr(239).chr(241).chr(242).chr(243)
            .chr(244).chr(245).chr(246).chr(248).chr(249).chr(250).chr(251)
            .chr(252).chr(253).chr(255);

        $chars['out'] = "EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy";

        $string = strtr($string, $chars['in'], $chars['out']);
        $double_chars['in'] = array(chr(140), chr(156), chr(198), chr(208), chr(222), chr(223), chr(230), chr(240), chr(254));
        $double_chars['out'] = array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th');
        $string = str_replace($double_chars['in'], $double_chars['out'], $string);
    }

    return $string;
}


$str = "ľ š č ť ž ý á í é Č Á Ž Ý";
echo remove_accents($str); // Output: l s c t z y a i e C A Z Y
?>
```

Comment: Just in case somebody will look for a solution and land here. This function *does not* remove diacritical accents (aka [combining diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks).) Use `preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]+/u', '', $string)` or `preg_replace('/\pM+/u', '', $string)` to remove diacritical accents from string.

Comment: Why isn't the huge char array static?

Comment: I can't stress how thankful I am for this solution. When you search for this solution, everything you find involves iconv and ASCII. Neither on my local mac or remote Linux server would get get the right things - I'd get two-character replacements every time. This function worked 100% right for the search index I needed to create - if I could upvote 100 times I would!

Comment: yay! slovak keyboard example!

Comment: I noticed that 'ø' is missing. chr(195).chr(184) => 'o'

Answer (score 58):

if you have http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php available, you can use this:

```
$string = "Fóø Bår";
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Lower(); :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);
echo $normalized = $transliterator->transliterate($string);
```

Comment: That is an excellent answer that deserves more attention. Intl extension is widely available since it is bundled with PHP 5.3+ (it only need to be enabled at build).

Comment: This one worked for me! And is a general solution too, without the need to try and guess all the critical chars.

Comment: The only fully working solution that sanitizes all character sets. Thank You!

Comment: Definitely the best answer. Thank you!

Comment: Too bad this isn't properly documented in PHP. Works like a charm though :-)

Answer (score 15):

```
preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml|caron);/i','$1',htmlentities($value));
```

Comment: That's surprisingly compact and effective for most use cases.

Comment: Beware, though, that it would transform other characters escaped by `htmlentitites`.

Answer (score 12):

```
$table = array(
        ' '=>'-', 'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'C'=>'C', 'c'=>'c', 'C'=>'C', 'c'=>'c',
        'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
        'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
        'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
        'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
        'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
        'ÿ'=>'y', 'R'=>'R', 'r'=>'r', "'"=>'-', '"'=>'-'
    );

$string = strtr($url, $table);
```

Comment: Same here, `strtr` doesn't support multibyte characters.

Comment: Be aware that this array contains duplicate : `'C'=>'C', 'c'=>'c'` and `'ý'=>'y'`

Comment: This list is incomplete. Doing this without using standard thoroughly checked functionality is a recipe for failure.

Comment: Also, why `'R'=>'R', 'r'=>'r', "'"=>'-', '"'=>'-'` ?

Answer (score 5):

based on the reply of raugfer:

```
// removes diacritics from a string
$regexp = '/&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml|caron);/i';
echo html_entity_decode(preg_replace($regexp, '$1', htmlentities($str)));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a function for translating all characters in a string called [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).  You can basically just consider them to be different characters altogether, and translate them as such.

Comment: `strtr` doesn't support multibyte characters.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at CodeIgniter's `convert_accented_characters` function. It is defined in [system/helpers/text_helper.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/text_helper.php) and uses the array located at [application/config/foreign_chars.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/foreign_chars.php).

Here is what it does, in a nutshell:

```
$foreign_characters = array(
    '/ä|æ|ǽ/' => 'ae',
    '/ö|œ/' => 'oe',
    '/ü/' => 'ue',
    // etc.
);

$array_from = array_keys($foreign_characters);
$array_to = array_values($foreign_characters);

$result = preg_replace($array_from, $array_to, $str);
```

However, it is a bit slow as it does a bunch of regex replacements. Maybe I should give `iconv` and WordPress's `remove_accents` a try.

Answer (score 2):

If intl php extension is enabled, you can use Transliterator like this :

```
protected function removeDiacritics($string)
{
    $transliterator = \Transliterator::create('NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;');
    return $transliterator->transliterate($string);
}
```

To remove other special chars (not diacritics only like 'æ')

```
protected function removeDiacritics($string)
{
    $transliterator = \Transliterator::createFromRules(
        ':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: NFC;',
        \Transliterator::FORWARD
    );
    return $transliterator->transliterate($string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the romainian characters. In case you want to keep the characters as they are and save them into a database such as mysql ,use the html special characters code. Otherwise, if your goal is the second array, then use this code:

```
function diac($text)
{
    $diac = array('ľ','š','č','ť','ž','ý','á','í','é','Č','Á','Ž','Ý');
    $cor = array('l','s','c','t','z','y','a' ,'i' ,'e', 'C' ,'A', 'Z', 'Y');
    $text = str_replace($diac,$cor,$text);
    return $text;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fn_normalize($s) { // Replaces all diacritics/accents
    return transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; Lower()', $s);
}

$a = [" Válue1  ", "válue2 ", "válue3", "Café à la carte", "A æ Übérmensch på høyeste nivå! И я люблю PHP! ﬁ"];

$result = array_map('fn_normalize', $a);

var_dump($result);
```

This worked for me. You might have to edit line 934 of your **php.ini**

> ;extension=intl

Remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful for anybody: https://github.com/infralabs/DiacriticsRemovePHP

The full post with usage example and source/result comparison is in this thread:
[Change foreign characters to normal equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837148/change-foreign-characters-to-normal-equivalent/26673362#26673362)