# R: Replace all punctuated letters with normal letters

Tags: r

I am looking for an easy way to replace all punctuated letters with normal letters. For example, I want to change `föó` to `foo`. I can do this as such:

```
gsub("ö|ó","o","föó")
```

however, it will probably be a lot of manual work to do this for every possible punctuated letter. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: The accents and other symbols are called *diacritics*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try some variation of this:

```
    cleanString <- function(x){
        tmp <- iconv(x, from="UTF8", to ="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
        gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", tmp)
        }

x = "föó"

cleanString(x)

[1] "foo"
```

idea for using iconv from [Remove diacritics from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string)

Comment: it should take a character vector (i.e. `x = c("föó", "zöó")`) as well.

Comment: Thanks, looks awesome. I get NA when I try it with `ü` though: `cleanString('ü')`

Comment: @Sacha - it works for me. I have a feeling it is going to be system-dependent, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sacha it seems to work for me on Windows if I change the from argument to `"latin1"` or just leave as `""` (system default).