# jQuery typeahead.js and accents

Tags: jquery, special-characters, typeahead.js

I'm using the jQuery typeahead plugin to autocomplete countries in both french and english.

It works ok, even when accents are used as the countries are fetched the way they should in both languages.
The only thing is that, as soon as the user types manually the accents, the input field stops displaying the hint.

Ultimately this is how it evolves as the user types the word:

**A** lgérie ok)

**Al** gérie (ok)

**Alg** érie (ok)

**Algé** (not ok)

**Algér** (not ok)

**Algéri** (not ok)

**Algérie**

Keep in mind that the box below the input field (showing all the words matching the input) will keep on displaying "Algérie", as expected, even when the hint is not displayed anymore.

So, it seems that there is nothing wrong with MySQL as the data is clearly fetched and the accent recognized as such but the hint will just not work as soon as the user has typed the accent (but before typing this accent, the hint will display the accent, that's not a problem).

What can I do about that?

This is how I call the plugin:

```
$('.filterbox_location').typeahead({
    remote : 'library/other/filter_validate/autocomplete_location.php?query=%QUERY',
    minLength: 1
});
```

I don't display the php script as it is irrelevant since it is clear that the data is fetched. The problem comes afterward when typeahead is handling the input.

If necessary, I will give the php code of course.

Comment: What do you see as your query value on the server side?

Comment: I get the proper words (Algeria and Algérie). Maybe I didn't get you. What do you mean by "What do you see"? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check the solution I proposed at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35247090/2612437

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this recent solution: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/271

Regards!

Comment: The link is inconclusive on a solution, any chance of getting a solution that can actually be posted on SO

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
// modulo-1
// ----------
var charMap = {
    "à": "a",
    "á": "a",
    "â": "a",
    "é": "e",
    "è": "e",
    "ê": "e",
    "ë": "e",
    "É": "e",
    "ï": "i",
    "î": "i",
    "ô": "o",
    "ö": "o",
    "û": "u",
    "ù": "u",
    "ü": "u",
    "ñ": "n"    
};

var names = ["Algérie", "Panamá","México"];

var normalize = function (input) {
    $.each(charMap, function (unnormalizedChar, normalizedChar) {
        var regex = new RegExp(unnormalizedChar, 'gi');
        input = input.replace(regex, normalizedChar);
    });
    return input;
};

var queryTokenizer = function (q) {
    var normalized = normalize(q);
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(normalized);
};

var nombres = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: queryTokenizer,
    local: $.map(names, function (name) {
        // Normalize the name - use this for searching
        var normalized = normalize(name);
        return {
            value: normalized,
            // Include the original name - use this for display purposes
            displayValue: name
        };
    })
});

nombres.initialize();

$('#search').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    hint: false,
    highlight: true
}, {
    displayKey: 'displayValue',
    source: nombres.ttAdapter()
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  *overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.tt-menu,
.gist {
  text-align: left;
}

/* base styles */
/* ----------- */

html {
  font: normal normal normal 18px/1.2 "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, "Segoe UI", Calibri, sans-serif;
  color: #292f33;
}


a {
  color: #03739c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.table-of-contents li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

.table-of-contents li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #999;
}

p + p {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

/* site theme */
/* ---------- */

.title {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.example {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.example-name {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
  *z-index: 1;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  width: 396px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
}

.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-menu {
  width: 422px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}

.gist {
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* example specific styles */
/* ----------------------- */

#custom-templates .empty-message {
  padding: 5px 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

#multiple-datasets .league-name {
  margin: 0 20px 5px 20px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#scrollable-dropdown-menu .tt-menu {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#rtl-support .tt-menu {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>Search for: "Algerie", "Panama" or "Mexico"</p>
<input id="search" class="typeahead" type="text">

<script  type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this other question at this link, it is related to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212974/typeahead-js-how-to-have-a-more-precise-search-and-ignoring-special-characters