# typeahead.js how to have a more precise search and ignoring special characters (Auto-complete script)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Follow the working demo below on JsFiddle

We have 2 fields, "modulo-1" and "modulo-2"

HTML:

```html
Módulo 1:<br>
<input id="modulo-1" class="typeahead" type="text">
<br>
<br>
Módulo 2:<br>
<input id="modulo-2" class="typeahead" type="text">

<script  type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  *overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.tt-menu,
.gist {
  text-align: left;
}

/* base styles */
/* ----------- */

html {
  font: normal normal normal 18px/1.2 "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, "Segoe UI", Calibri, sans-serif;
  color: #292f33;
}


a {
  color: #03739c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.table-of-contents li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

.table-of-contents li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #999;
}

p + p {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

/* site theme */
/* ---------- */

.title {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.example {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.example-name {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
  *z-index: 1;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  width: 396px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
}

.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-menu {
  width: 422px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}

.gist {
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* example specific styles */
/* ----------------------- */

#custom-templates .empty-message {
  padding: 5px 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

#multiple-datasets .league-name {
  margin: 0 20px 5px 20px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#scrollable-dropdown-menu .tt-menu {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#rtl-support .tt-menu {
  text-align: right;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
// modulo-1
// ----------
var charMap = {
    "à": "a",
    "á": "a",
    "â": "a",
    "é": "e",
    "è": "e",
    "ê": "e",
    "ë": "e",
    "É": "e",
    "ï": "i",
    "î": "i",
    "ô": "o",
    "ö": "o",
    "û": "u",
    "ù": "u",
    "ü": "u",
    "ñ": "n"    
};

var names = ["série:Aladdin", "personagem:Naruto","paródia:Dragon Ball Z"];

var normalize = function (input) {
    $.each(charMap, function (unnormalizedChar, normalizedChar) {
        var regex = new RegExp(unnormalizedChar, 'gi');
        input = input.replace(regex, normalizedChar);
    });
    return input;
};

var queryTokenizer = function (q) {
    var normalized = normalize(q);
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(normalized);
};

var nombres = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: queryTokenizer,
    local: $.map(names, function (name) {
        // Normalize the name - use this for searching
        var normalized = normalize(name);
        return {
            value: normalized,
            // Include the original name - use this for display purposes
            displayValue: name
        };
    })
});

nombres.initialize();

$('#modulo-1').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    hint: false,
    highlight: true
}, {
    displayKey: 'displayValue',
    source: nombres.ttAdapter()
});







// modulo-2
// ----------
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring q
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring q, add it to the matches array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ["série:Aladdin", "personagem:Naruto","paródia:Dragon Ball Z"];

$('#modulo-2').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
                         {
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avcurdgy/2/

In module-1, it's almost the way I want it, in it I can search for "série" or "serie" and it gives me the value I need. But when I search for "naruto" it returns nothing.

Now in "modulo-2" when I search for "naruto" it can find the result, but it doesn't ignore the accents, if I search for "serie" it doesn't return anything.

I need that in module-1 when I search for "naruto" it finds the result as in module-2, I tried a lot here for several days, but without success.

Could someone help me?

typeahead.js documentation:
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/