# Listing by alphabetical order not ignoring special characters like "Ó"

Tags: php

I got some search results listed alphabetically by groups like this:

A --
Andre, Amalia...

B --
Bart, Bruno,
etc...

The problem is, if some name starts with a special character like "Ólga"
i got another group like this:

Ó --
Olga

My question: How to list names starting with "Ó" inside the group "O"? Thanks.

My code:

```
<?php
$previous = null;
foreach($rows as $row1) {
 $firstLetter = substr($row1->titolo, 0, 1);
  if($previous !== $firstLetter) echo $firstLetter."<br />";
$previous = $firstLetter;
  echo $row1->titolo;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can use the `Collator` class

*Provides string comparison capability with support for appropriate locale-sensitive sort orderings*

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php

Comment: yeap...by far better that previous answers like  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837148/change-foreign-characters-to-their-normal-equivalent

Comment: Looks like a useful tool, but how would you use the Collator class to solve this specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

The class Collator is part of the intl extension, so if you don't have it or you can't install it, I suggest you to use this utility conversion array in this answer [Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

```
<?php
$unwanted_array = array('Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                        'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                        'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                        'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
$previous = null;
foreach($rows as $row1) {
    $firstLetter = substr($row1->titolo, 0, 1);
    $firstLetter = strtr( $firstLetter, $unwanted_array );
    if($previous !== $firstLetter) echo $firstLetter."<br />";
    $previous = $firstLetter;
    echo $row1->titolo;
}
?>
```

Comment: Oops... so sorry. In different examples I tried it worked properly. May I know what's the problem with this solution?