# How to use substr in php to ignore accented characters?

Tags: php, utf-8, substr

I am working on a php code as shown below which prints H

```
echo substr("Hello world",0, 1);
```

Now, I have an accented Ĥ in Ĥello. The following code prints �.

```
echo substr("Ĥello world",0, 1);
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **second echo statement** above with **Ĥello world** as the string so that it prints **H** instead of **�**.

**Note:** I want the second echo statement to return **H** not **Ĥ**. Only H

I have used the following code but it seems to return **Ĥ** not **H**

`echo mb_substr("Ĥello world",0, 1);`

Comment: have you tried `mb_substr("hello world",0,1,"utf-8")` ?

Comment: Its printing blank in my code.

Comment: Although, its working fine here http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: for me both `substr()` and `mb_substr()` return `H` and not `Ĥ`

Comment: which php version are you using? can you tell in brief about your environment?

Comment: Can you send me the o/p in fiddle like the way Alive has sent ?

Comment: In your comment above, you are using h not accented h.

Comment: To what purpose are you doing this?

Comment: `echo substr("Ĥello world",0, 1);` you have `Ĥ` in your code and you want to convert it to `H`. am i right?

Comment: @danish yes, can it be possible through substr() ?

Comment: @Qirel Here is my actual code https://3v4l.org/jKsiW The place where I am using `echo $title_char;` I want this echo return non-accented characters.

Comment: But for what purpose are you doing this? What's the underlying reason for wanting to replace data? Is it because you are having encoding issues (so Ĥ is printed as �)?

Comment: you need to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837148/change-foreign-characters-to-their-normal-equivalent)

Comment: check this out [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) `iconv()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: checkout this [link](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/simple-url-cleanser-in-php/)