# Fulltext search in PHP

Tags: php, full-text-search

I want to perform fulltext search for a given phrase in a given string using PHP.

I want this search to be:

- case insensitive
- diacritics insensitive, so for example "Žluťoučký kůň" should be matched as "Zlutoucky kun"
- as fast as possible
- independent on any third party libraries (if it is possible)

Can you help me? ...I am sorry for creating new post, I've searched a lot, before I asked. However, I found only posts that concerned with PHP+MySQL search.

Comment: There are whole books dedicated to "how to do full text search", so the question is probably too broad for here (we tend to encourage questions where something has been attempted, and some code can be shown). You should get some pointers in the comments though. To start you off: have you looked into MySQL's full-text search?

Comment: I recently used Zend's Lucene library for this, as I'm on MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB tables, and InnoDB didn't get full text search capability until 5.6. Lucene seems OK to me, not really tested it for speed though (note that in most cases where speed is specified as important, it isn't really - fast enough is nearly always good enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [remove diacritics from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string) and then need to use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: This isn't full text search though - I think full text does weighting based on the quality of match i.e. whether phrases are matched together, number of matching words, sometimes word stemming as well.

Comment: You have right. But @Michal did not mention weighting based search.

Comment: I think weighting can be implied, but either way, my point is that a regex is not a [full-text search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).

Comment: I apologize for possible misinterpretation of my question, but Stanislav Komanec's solution is what I've been searching for. But can't that diacritic removal operation for the whole text to slow?

Comment: Yes, it is slow, but I don't know faster way.

Answer (score 1):

How [MYSQL Full-Text Search](https://groups.hyvor.com/PHP/200/mysql-fulltext-search-in-php) work is complex compared to PHP [preg match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). For example, [stop words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes) are considered in MYSQL full text search.

If you only need to depend on PHP, (and no libraries) you will need to do some development. [Here's](https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch) a popular library created like that.

Answer (score 0):

For full text search i know 2 common solutions:

1. Use MYISAM FULLTEXT index http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

So, if you have InnoDB table, you must copy searchable info into MYISAM table (for example use triggers)

2. Use external special search engines. For example:

   - Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/
   - Elastic search http://www.elasticsearch.org/