# Smarty (.tpl) remove accents from a url

Tags: smarty

I have a variable in a .tpl file (smarty) The variable name is:

```
{$topic.url}
```

This variable returns a url. (It is not always the same url)

**The problem**:
Some urls returned by this variable have accents.

Example:

```
http://someserver.com/forum/ántigüedad-con-énfasis
```

How I can do to remove all accents, and the variable return something like...

```
http://someserver.com/forum/antiguedad-con-enfasis
```

I have only access to the .tpl file, so I can not edit any php file. The solution should be added in the same .tpl file.

Thanks.

Comment: You could write a custom modifier. There are different ways to remove the accents / diacritics. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string More information about custom modifiers http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://someserver.com/forum/ántigüedad-con-énfasis';
$url = strtr($url, array('á' => 'a', 'ü' => 'u', 'é' => 'e'));
$smarty->assign('url', $url);
```