# in_array returns false on same characters, single character string matching

Tags: php

```
function make_ascii($str) {
    $special = array('ľ','š','č','ť','ž','ý','á','í','é','ú','ä','ô','ň','ě');
    $ascii =   array('l','s','c','t','z','y','a','i','e','u','a','o','n','e');
    $str = str_split($str);
    foreach ($str as $k => $c) {
        if(ctype_upper($c)) {
            $u = true;
            $c = strtolower($c);
        } else {
            $u = false;
        }
        if(in_array($c, $special, false)) {
            $c = $ascii[array_search($c, $special)];
        }
        if($u) {
            $c = strtoupper($c);
        }
        $str[$k] = $c;
    }
    return join($str);
}
```

In this function, even if I feed characters from `$special` array the `in_array()` returns false every time, if I would `var_dump()` on regular text I try to parse, the output will be just `bool(false)` with no mach, even if I copy paste the character from source to array. Also I'm looking for way to make this character replacement work.

Comment: you have a return at the first line?

Comment: `str_split` does not work properly on multibyte strings.

Comment: remove this `return $str;` from first line

Comment: sorry, that return was just placed there to keep whole script working

Comment: `array_seach` is also wrong

Comment: Is this the full set of the special characters you want to replace? There are a few questions that provide more general solutions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

As `str_split`will not work for multibyte you have to use `mb_`to perform multibyte string operation

```
function make_ascii($str) {
    //return $str;
    $special = array('ľ','š','č','ť','ž','ý','á','í','é','ú','ä','ô','ň','ě');
    $ascii =   array('l','s','c','t','z','y','a','i','e','u','a','o','n','e');
    $str = array_map(function ($i) use ($str) { 
    return mb_substr($str, $i, 1); 
}, range(0, mb_strlen($str) -1));
    foreach ($str as $k => $c) {
        if(ctype_upper($c)) {
            $u = true;
            $c = strtolower($c);
        } else {
            $u = false;
        }
       // print_r($c);
        if(in_array($c, $special)) {
            $c = $ascii[array_search($c, $special)];
        }
        if($u) {
            $c = strtoupper($c);
        }
        $str[$k] = $c;
    }
    return join($str);
}
var_dump(make_ascii('áé'));
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/HYlqj)

If issue with uppercase letters you have to change functions to `mb_strtoupper` and `mb_strtolower`. Also `ctype_upper` will not work so change it also

```
function make_ascii($str) {
    //return $str;
    $special = array('ľ','š','č','ť','ž','ý','á','í','é','ú','ä','ô','ň','ě');
    $ascii =   array('l','s','c','t','z','y','a','i','e','u','a','o','n','e');
    $str = array_map(function ($i) use ($str) { 
    return mb_substr($str, $i, 1); 
}, range(0, mb_strlen($str) -1));

    foreach ($str as $k => $c) {
        if( mb_strtoupper($c, "UTF-8") == $c) {
            $u = true;
            $c = mb_strtolower($c);
        } else {
            $u = false;
        }
       // print_r($c);
        if(in_array($c, $special)) {
            $c = $ascii[array_search($c, $special)];
        }
        if($u) {
            $c = mb_strtoupper($c);
        }
        $str[$k] = $c;
    }
    return join($str);
}
$str = "ľÁľa ýellow";
var_dump(make_ascii($str));
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Bo1SF)

Comment: sounds good, demo is working, but somehow here on my text it doesn't get past in_array, that always gets false.

Comment: Sidenote: (also I realised for my answer too), `strtolower` will also not work. We probalby need [`mb_strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

Comment: check your string https://3v4l.org/Y9ZOh If you have diffrent string give that string

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned `str_split` can't handle multi-byte strings. Don't believe me? [Have a look.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4c7f4dedca20b85014cc6b41d084ea66261e735)

At any rate here's a version that can split multibyte strings:

```
function make_ascii($str) {

    $special = array('ľ','š','č','ť','ž','ý','á','í','é','ú','ä','ô','ň','ě');
    $ascii =   array('l','s','c','t','z','y','a','i','e','u','a','o','n','e');
    $str = preg_split("//u",$str);
    foreach ($str as $k => $c) {
        if(ctype_upper($c)) {
            $u = true;
            $c = mb_strtolower($c);
        } else {
            $u = false;
        }
        if(in_array($c, $special, false)) {
            $c = $ascii[array_search($c, $special)];
        }
        if($u) {
            $c = mb_strtoupper($c);
        }
        $str[$k] = $c;
    }
    return join($str);
}

$str = "ľaľa ýellow";

print_r(make_ascii($str));
```

[Prints:](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/098cbd8ea1c55f7b33aad6c69b47799fa5731700)

> lala yellow