# How to Convert Special Chars to Standard Chars?

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters

I'm looking for way to convert chars like *āžšķūņrūķīš* to *azskunrukis*. In other words, to replace *ā* with *a*, *ž* with *z* and so. Is there anything built-in, or I should create my own "library" of from-to symbols?

Comment: What is the purpose of this conversion? If you want to make URLs out of that I'd rather recommend you to get UTF-8 encoded URLs right as gooogle will like them much more than crippled text in non english languages. Most modern browsers will also show them correctly in the address bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle diacritics (accents) when rewriting 'pretty URLs'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465990/how-to-handle-diacritics-accents-when-rewriting-pretty-urls)

Comment: Just keep in mind that e.g., ü and u are _very_ different letters.

Comment: Check this, it worked for me :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257810/10159774

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [iconv's transliteration capabilities](http://php.net/function.iconv):

```
<?php
$text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;

?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

> Original : This is the Euro symbol '€'.
>   TRANSLIT : This is the Euro symbol 'EUR'.
>   IGNORE   : This is the Euro symbol ''.
>   Plain    :
>   Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in .\iconv-example.php on line 7
>   This is the Euro symbol '

Your example text can be tranliterated using:

```
$translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'āžšķūņrūķīš');
```

Here's an example with the text you provided: http://ideone.com/MJHvf

Comment: I think he wants `iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'āžšķūņrūķīš');` rather than to convert to ISO-8859-1, but otherwise this is the answer. Here's a [non-iconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542818/remove-accents-without-using-iconv) answer for people without it.

Comment: Sweet, we wouldn't want this guy to get only a B on his homework. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any functions that do this directly, but there are some implementations of translation tables that do something like that in the comments on [`strtr`'s documentation page](http://php.net/function.strtr#90925).  They end up using a table that directly translates each character to its equivalent, i.e. "ž" => "z".

Comment: how to convert "Hello & World " as in html it only displays Hello . But in view source we can view whole word

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `iconv`, you could check out the [`Normalize`](http://php.net/normalizer.normalize) functions of the intl extension (if available).