# How can my mysql query change 'Şarapçı Çağ' to 'Sarapci-Cag'

Tags: php, mysql, text, web, converters

How can my mysql query change `Şarapçı Çağ` to `Sarapci-Cag`

I tried this:

```
SELECT CONVERT('Şarapçı Çağ' USING latin1) -> ?arapç? Ça?
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is the logic behind the insertio of a hyphen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting the result you can change like:

```
"ş","ţ","ă" by "s","t","a" using str_replace.
```

or you can visit here:[PHP converting special characters, like ş to s, ţ to t, ă to a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252938/php-converting-special-characters-like-%C5%9F-to-s-%C5%A3-to-t-%C4%83-to-a)

Comment: Is there any way to change on query.

Comment: I try SELECT  REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( u_grup, 'ü', 'u' ) , 'ç', 'c' ) , 'ö', 'o' ) , 'ı', 'i' ) , 'ş', 's' ) , 'ğ', 'g' ) , 'Ü', 'U' ) , 'Ç', 'C' ) , 'Ö', 'O' ) , 'Ş', 'S' ), ' ', '_' ) AS yeni
FROM urunler

Comment: here you can see conversion using utf8:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: end of search: Couldn't multiple convert to ş to s, ı to i, Ç to C in mysql query.