# Convert a view in utf-8 using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, codeigniter-2, utf8-decode

I have a problem with encoding, I tried to convert my html in utf8 using CodeIgniter, so my code is:

```
public function generateTitlePage($company)
{
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $search = array('%27', '%20', '%C3%A2', '%C3%AE');
    $replace = array('', ' ', 'â', 'î');
    $company = str_replace($search, $replace, $company);
    $html = '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold">
               LIMITATĂ'.$company.'
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
    ';


    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
}
```

So, my output pdf is LIMITAT? name of company,I dont't understand why Ă is not converted is use meta tag, also I use Codeigniter config: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; Help me pleaaaaase, thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct conversion method.you have to use `str_replace or something similar`.for more info you can see this:[PHP converting special characters, like ş to s, ţ to t, ă to a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252938/php-converting-special-characters-like-%C5%9F-to-s-%C5%A3-to-t-%C4%83-to-a)