# Replace Accented Characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

I've been reading a few other questions but I am still stuck on the problem of converting strings containing accented characters into plain characters (by which I mean a-z)

I have a product name "Áhkká" which is already encoded as `"&Aacute;hkk&aacute;"`

I want to decode this to the string with accents, and then convert it to read "Ahkka"

So far, I have tried:

```
function convert($name) {
   $name = html_entity_decode($name,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
   $name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name);
   return $name;
}
```

I get an error from iconv: "Detected an illegal character in input string"

I have also tried using htmlspecialchars_decode($name); but that gives me �hkk�

I also found a string replace function to clear accents, but I can't seem to pass a non-html string to it

```
$name = strtr($name,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
```

Can someone please offer a solution? The server is running PHP 5.2.13. iconv is enabled glibc 2.5 (input/internal/output encoding is ISO-8859-1 in phpinfo)

Comment: Looks good to me http://ideone.com/UrGfn

Comment: `I have a product name "Áhkká" which is already encoded as "&Aacute;hkk&aacute;"` <- why are you storing the html representation of the string in the first place?

Comment: Looks like your syntax error is from forgetting a semicolon: `return $name;`

Comment: @Musa - I still get ?hkk?, Mahn, the data comes from a 3rd party (CSV data) so I have no control over this. GigaWatt - thanks, I updated my question, but this isn't the problem.

Comment: Try converting it back to utf-8 after the transliteration.

Comment: @Musa setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_GB.utf8'); fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to find a solution to your problem I have found this question:

[multibyte strtr() -> mb_strtr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758736/multibyte-strtr-mb-strtr)

In the chosen answer Alix Axel writes a function which is exactly what you need:

```
function Unaccent($string)
{
    return preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml|caron);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}

echo Unaccent(html_entity_decode('&Aacute;hkk&aacute;'));
```

prints `Ahkka`

Comment: This looks promising, but I end up with "ampaacutehkkampaacute" as the output. I isolated my code and that was the output. I've updated my answer with the test code based on your answer. Perhaps I need to set my default charset?

Comment: Have you tried decoding html entities with the parameters you used before? `html_entity_decode($name,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");` Do you get a proper UTF-8 string after decoding? If you do the `Unaccent` function should work well.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Your code did indeed work, but I also need to remove &#39; type entries. Secondly, This code will be run around 400,000 times along with 2 more preg_replace to make a "clean" url - to clean some product URLs - is this the fastest way?

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it is a solution, although in the end I did use iconv (needed to setlocate);