# strtr acting weird - removing diacritics from a string

Tags: php, strtr

I'm having hard times removing diacritics from some `$string`. My code is

```
<?php
$string = "Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.";
$without_diacritics = strTr($string, "říšžťčýůúěďó", "risztcyuuedo");
echo $without_diacritics;
```

while expected output would be `Prilis zlutoucky kun upel dabelske ody.`

Instead, I'm receiving very weird response:

```
Puiszliuc uuluueoudoks� ku�u� s�pd�l d�scbelsks� s�dy.
```

I've thought that it could be a problem with multi-byte characters, but I've found that the `strtr` is multi-byte safe. Is my assumption wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3635607/2518525) might be of some use (function based), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1770306/2518525).

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758736/multibyte-strtr-mb-strtr) ("multibyte strtr() -> mb_strtr()")

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I'll decide to use one of them for sure, but I am still looking forward to learn why doesn't my code work properly.

Comment: @Martin., it may be because some of those characters are more than one byte, so it doesn't map properly. Read [this](http://php.net/strtr#111270) comment, and try to use an associative array instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your input translation string is twice as big as the output translation string (because of Unicode) and `strtr()` works with bytes instead of characters; a translation array would be better in this case:

```php
$string = "Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.";

echo strtr($string, [
  'ř' => 'r',
  'í' => 'i',
  'š' => 's',
  'ž' => 'z',
  'ť' => 't',
  'č' => 'c',
  'ý' => 'y',
  'ů' => 'u',
  'ú' => 'u',
  'ě' => 'e',
  'ď' => 'd',
  'ó' => 'o'
]);
```

Output:

```
Prilis zlutoucky kuň upel dábelské ody.
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/278228)

Answer (score 1):

A simple and tried solution (based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770387/2518525)), harnesses [`iconv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the string "from your given encoding to ASCII characters".

```
$input = 'Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.';
$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);
echo $input;
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/278198)

---

Explanation

The issue you're facing is due to the encoding of the string/document. The issue with `strtr()` is that it isn't multibyte aware, as @ChrisForrence stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333931/strtr-acting-weird-removing-diacritics-from-a-string#comment45014808_28333931).

> It may be because some of those characters are more than one byte, so
> it doesn't map properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution gives me `P??li? ?lu?ou?k? k?? ?p?l ??belsk? ?dy.` for some reason. Is some internal PHP setting required to be set?

Comment: What PHP version are you using and what document encoding is your `.php` file?

Comment: It's encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. PHP Version 5.4.36-1