# Understanding key codes of characters

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

To summarize, I don't know what the difference is between the two words: "" & "Mexico". I need a clear understanding of this, and I want to know what conversion I need to do in PHP to make these two words the same.

I'm making a simple app that searches for strings using PHP/MySQL, HTML...(This is not important)

I want to search for sentences that contain the first word().

So If I enter the Mexico to the input box and submit then, the following SQL statement is executed  in the backend and produces the result.

```
SELECT * FROM `content` LIKE "%Mexico%"
```

The problem is that when the above query is executed, no results containing  are produced.

So I ran the following test:

```
$a = "";
$b = "Mexico";
if($a == $b) {
    echo "Same";
} else {
    echo "Not same";
}
```

And the result is "Not same".

I wondered if it was because the ASCII code was different, but I didn't know what to do.

I need a mysql solution because I need to retrieve these strings using SQL query from the DB.

Comment: There may be a difference in character encoding. Please check if `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php` helps you. All your strings should have the same encoding.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium nope, it has nothing to do with different encodings. The encoding is same - unicode

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201725/convert-fancy-unicode-abc-to-standard-abc

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081507/remove-strange-font-coding

Comment: Thank you @Your Common Sense. It's work as like magic.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this in a MySQL query?
I have over 100 million rows of records in a DB table and I need to do a string search on them. Because this method is a PHP solution, it is very inefficient because it requires importing 100 million rows of records into PHP, converting the strings, and then performing a conditional search.

Comment: So use PHP to _update_ your database content accordingly, _once_?

Comment: That could be a solution, but I don't want to change the string displayed in the user interface.
ex: I would like to keep the text format like this: https://i.imgur.com/PHh5jpQ.png
For reference, I use mysql v8.0.33

Comment: then you need to add another columns with normalized data

Comment: I think the linked questions pretty much answer it, but to make a short summary... Computers don't understand text the way people do. What matters is how a given symbol is represented as a series of bits. On top of that, you can implement rules to determine that two different sets of bits represent the same letter in certain context (e.g. "`E` is uppercase version of `e`"). I highly recommend [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9D%90%8C%F0%9D%90%9E%F0%9D%90%B1%F0%9D%90%A2%F0%9D%90%9C%F0%9D%90%A8Mexico).

Comment: If you just want to _compare_ for strings being the same, and you are using MySQL:  `SELECT "" = "Mexico";` yields true.  The default `COLLATION` in MySQL 8.0 achieves that for most cases.  MySQL does not have a way to _convert_ one to the other; various links in the Comments provide ways to _convert_ in shell and PHP.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames for your answer. But I did compare operation in mysql but I didn't get that result.
This is why I mentioned this issue. As a result, I am building a search app and this problem was raised as an issue because this string search does not work in mysql 8.0.
So, the current most logical solution is to convert the strange string to a regular string using the PHP function, then put it in an additional field even if the table size increases, and perform a string search using that field.

Comment: @WebStar - What collation was in effect -- both in the table and for the connection?  Declare the column _and_ connect with `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

Comment: Don't ever rely on default MySQL collation for complex searches like this. Either set it explicitly at table or column level (you always need a sensible known collation anyway), or set it at [query level](https://dbfiddle.uk/BY6Silk-) if the use case is very specific.