# PHP: URL friendly strings

Tags: php, string, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle diacritics (accents) when rewriting 'pretty URLs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465990/how-to-handle-diacritics-accents-when-rewriting-pretty-urls)

I want to replace special characters, such as Å Ä Ö Ü é, with "normal" characters (those between a-z and 0-9). And spaces should certainly be replaced with dashes, but that's not really a problem.

In other words, I want to turn this:

> en räksmörgås

into this:

> en-raksmorgas

What's the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465990/how-to-handle-diacritics-accents-when-rewriting-pretty-urls

Comment: Hm, didn't see that one - I don't really find its title that describing. Thank you for notice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) for the string replacement...

```
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```

Basically, it'll [transliterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) the characters it can, and drop those it can't (that are not in the ASCII character set)...

Then, just replace the spaces with `str_replace`:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
```

Or, if you want to get fancy, you can replace all consecutive white-space characters with a single dash using a simple regex:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\\s+/', '-', $string);
```

**Edit** As @Robert Ros points out, you need to set the locale prior to using `iconv` (Depending on the defaults of your system).  Just execute this line prior to the `iconv` line:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF8');
```

Comment: +1 also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration 
Btw, it's important your locale is set correctly for iconv transliteraion to work properly.

Comment: @Robert Ros: Thanks, I've added that to the answer...

Comment: Wonderful! But instead of 'ä' I get 'a"'. Not a big problem, I just have to run a preg_replace to remove everything but the characters. But is it ment to be so? I'm just curious.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I always wondered why sometimes iconv transliteration work and sometimes it didn't.

Comment: Huh?  You get a quote character?  I tested it on my machine, and it worked fine (I got your expected output).  Did you run `setlocale` first?

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda weird. I'm running the setlocale function above the iconv line, but my output is: r"aksm"orgas

Comment: The difference in transliteration appears to be based on PHP version:  5.2.9 transliterates both `à` and `ä` into `a`, as expected.  But PHP 5.4 transliterates those into `'a` and `"a` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

```
<?php
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
?>
```

Comment: But in this case I have to list all those special characters - I want to avoid that.

Comment: Yep. In such case, i think @ircmaxell's answer fits better. :)

Answer (score 0):

A clever hack often used for this is calling [htmlentitites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), then running

```
preg_replace('/&(\w)(acute|uml|circ|tilde|ring|grave);/', '\1', $str);
```

to get rid of the diacritics. A more complete (but often unnecessarily complicated) solution is using a Unicode decomposition algorithm to split diacritics, then dropping everything that is not an ASCII letter or digit.